# htmlagilitypack strange behaviour when using 2 htmldocument objects

Tags: object, html-agility-pack, dom, selectsinglenode

Here is the code:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
HtmlDocument segment = new HtmlDocument();

htmlDoc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
segment.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;            

htmlDoc.Load("sourcepath");
segment.Load("sourcepath");

//Fix HtmlAgilityPack bug with ending tag at xmldeclaration
var newNodeStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
var newNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(newNodeStr);
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode, htmlDoc.DocumentNode.FirstChild);
segment.DocumentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode, segment.DocumentNode.FirstChild);    

HtmlNode sbodyNode = segment.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
if (sbodyNode != null)
sbodyNode.RemoveAllChildren();

HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
int numberOfChilds = bodyNode.ChildNodes.Count;
MessageBox.Show(numberOfChilds.ToString());

segment.Save("destpath1", Encoding.UTF8);
htmlDoc.Save("destpath2", Encoding.UTF8);
```

Input is simple xhtml. I want to modify an xhtml file(this is represented by htmlDoc). For this i created another HtmlDocument object(segment, load the same xhtml into it). As a first step i am trying to strip all the children of the body element. Then i would add some of the elements back using htmlDoc obeject. The problem with the above is that removing these from segment affects htmlDoc(the other object) too. So the MessageBox will show 0 always. On top of this if i look at the outputs, which is produced by the Save functions, htmlDoc will have elements under the , which would mean that the MessageBox should show the number of them(as far as  i guess).(Note: If i uncomment the RemoveAllChildren() line then the MessageBox shows the correct number.)
I think its some trivial stuff, but it's kinda strange for me. Thanks for your help.

**Update:** Sorry i didn't post the full code beacuse i thought some lines are irrelevant, but looks like they are not. If i comment out those 4 lines after the Loads, i get the right numbers and it works like expected. The question is why those lines do "harm". (these lines i wrote to fix the output, because agilitypack made the xml header closing tag /> instead of ?>)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with your exact code. I get 6 childnodes (with my example html file) And the debugger shows 0 childnodes for the other sbodyNode.ChildNodes.Count.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying out and let me realize that i have to post full code next time. I thought some lines are irrelevant ot the problem and left them out. Sorry for that, see details in the post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15992718/3137362 real problem is described here

Answer (score 0):

The following solves my problem, but not sure why. If anybody care to explain i would be greatful.

```
var newNodeStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
var newNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(newNodeStr);
var newNode2 = HtmlNode.CreateNode(newNodeStr);
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode, htmlDoc.DocumentNode.FirstChild);
segment.DocumentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode2, segment.DocumentNode.FirstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite logical. ReplaceChild doesn't clone the child node, it just inserts the reference. So if you call ClearChildNodes() on it, it will be cleared in all documents where the reference was added. It looks like HtmlNode implements CloneNode, CopyTo and Clone. One of these methods should be called to insert a copy of your node into each document.

```
var newNodeStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
var newNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(newNodeStr);

htmlDoc.DocumentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode.CloneNode(true), htmlDoc.DocumentNode.FirstChild);
segment.DocumentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode.CloneNode(true), segment.DocumentNode.FirstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack has a bug when you are adding or removing or replacing elements when you are using the "watch" and you are debugging... to fix this strange behavior, clear your watch list in debug mode...