# Ghosty HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have got really ghosty effect here.
I try to replace an img node. and if I print out the document html once, nothing will happen. 
If I don't print out the document html, the img tag can be successfully replaced. 
It's really strange, can anyone explain?[image]

my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="swap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my c# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.IO;
namespace htmlagile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlDocument htmldoc = new HtmlDocument();
            string htmlstring;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("HTMLPage1.html"))
            {
                htmlstring = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            htmldoc.LoadHtml(htmlstring);
            var div = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div");

            Console.WriteLine(htmldoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);

            foreach (var item in div)
            {
                HtmlNode newTag = htmldoc.CreateElement("p");
                newTag.SetAttributeValue("id", "change");
                item.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newTag, item);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(htmldoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
        }
    }
}
```

if I comment out my first console.WriteLine, the  element can be successfully changed.

[image]

Comment: Lack of detailed info to troubleshoot. The snapshot is less legible.

Comment: hi David
i have attached full code. Any idea??

Comment: No reasons. Are you sure this is due to your first print?

Comment: i don't know.
if i comment my writeline, only that very one line, the element can be changed.
And then, I try to get a clone of the html document, it gets the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug in the agility pack. They cache the OuterHtml and InnerHtml values. When a change happens, they only invalidate the immediate parent. Because you are printing the root, it still has the old cached value.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/30053

If you change to printing out the parent div, you should see that the changes actually were performed:

```
Console.WriteLine(div.OuterHtml);
```

Comment: it's true, but what can i do about this?
is there anyway to refresh the cache?

Comment: You can try modifying the root html node or you can edit the agility pack source to fix the bug as done here: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/30053

Comment: thank you though, i decided to use the good old xmldocument
what's the advantage of htmlagilitypack except it's so buggy?
most of its functions are presented in xmldocument

Comment: Very little HTML you grab from the web is going to be XML compliant. The agility pack will allow you to parse HTML that XmlDocument can't. If you are generating all of the HTML yourself and can guarantee it's valid XML, XmlDocument should be OK.

Comment: @LouD  i tried modifing from the current node to till reach top node  didnt worked. 
i read the issue that you gave .   impact low? is he(hap creator) baka? why wont he fix it  ?  is he evil person?

Comment: It's not a very active project or maybe they consider it a feature? Did you try the newer fix in that same work item link: _changedField.SetValue(HtmlDocument.DocumentNode, true);